# Why plt.savefig() is saving image that has some size but when I open it, It is blank?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I save figure in matplotlib, the figure gets saved and has some size as well but when I open it, It is blank and I cannot open it using Ipython.display.Image as well
below is the code snippet

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
'2.1.2'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x =np.linspace(0,10,100)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),'-')

plt.plot(x,np.cos(x),'--')
fig.savefig('my_figure.png',dpi=300)
from IPython.display import Image
Image('my_figure.png')
```

This code is from "Python Data Science handbook" and I am copying it as it is.

Comment: cannot reproduce your result, pls kindly upgrade your matplotlib version. it might solve your issue.

Comment: I ugraded my matplotlib version to 3.1.2 . But the problem still exists.

Comment: I am using 3.3.1. cannot reproduce , but I dont think it's a matplotlib issue, try another image reader or viewer?

Comment: I am not sure other image reader or viewer would help because when I open the saved image with Windows Photo or ms paint ,it is blank.

Comment: The issue got resolved. I was using separate cell in jupyter notebook for each line of code. Now I have clubbed below code in one cell and it is working

```x =np.linspace(0,10,100)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),'-')

plt.plot(x,np.cos(x),'--');
```

Sorry @ted930511 for asking silly question. I am new to python and Matplotlib. Do you have any explanation why it worked in a single cell but not in multiple cell.  Help appreciated.